# Transforming a uniform PDF to a Gaussian PDF

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, uniform-distribution, transform

I have a Uniform PDF from [-50, 50], I would like to transform it to a Gaussian. The methods that I read up about doing this(like Box Mueller) assume that the uniform distribution is between [0,1). Is there any way to do this for [-50,50]. Is there any translation or scaling that may be done for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Muller not Mueller. No umlaut and only one e in the original. Open access to original paper at https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177706645

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sample $U \sim \text{Unif}[-50,50]$ and then transform it into $U' = (U+50)/100$, making $U' \sim \text{Unif}[0,1]$, at which point you may apply the Box-Muller transform to the transformed random varible $U'$.